# How to open .ctl file in python

Tags: python, ctl

I have a control file named co2_prior.ctl
I've written the code.

```
from xgrads import open_CtlDataset

dset = open_CtlDataset('co2_prior.ctl')
```

But it is throwing error.The error message is "unsupported format: %y4_22sat/CO2pri_gmc3t"
Can anyone help me?